# Convert out parameter of constructor to a tuple to use in pattern matching in F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I [have read](http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2010/07/f-pattern-matching-for-beginners-part-2-decomposition.html) that F# is smart enough to convert out parameter of a method to tuple. For example:

```
let isInt s =
  match System.Int32.TryParse(s) with
  | (false, _) -> false
  | (true, _) -> true
```

I want to create a new Mutex with unique system-wide name. There's a constructor with 3 parameters:

```
new: 
    initiallyOwned:bool * 
    name:string * 
    createdNew:bool byref -> Mutex
```

Last parameter is out parameter and F# should be able to convert constructor call result to a tuple.
Nevertheless the following code looks fails to compile with the error "*This expression was expected to have type Mutex but here has type 'a * 'b*"

```
open System.Threading

let rec CreateUniqueMutex i =
    match new Mutex(false, i.ToString()) with
    | (_, false) -> CreateUniqueMutex (i+1) // Error here
    | (mutex, true) -> mutex
```

What is the difference with the first **isInt** method?

Can my code be fixed?

What would be the best-looking code for my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that there are multiple overloads of the `Mutex` constructor, so the compiler thinks that you're calling the overload which takes exactly two arguments.  Your best bet is to declare a mutable local and use that:

```
let rec createUniqueMutex i =
    let mutable b = false
    let mutex = new Mutex(false, string i, &b)
    if b then mutex else createUniqueMutex (i+1)
```

Note that I've fixed a few other issues with your code.  In particular, you need to use `let rec` to define a recursive function and you need to parenthesize `(i+1)`.

**Edit**

Just to show that this would work if it weren't for the overloads:

```
type MyType(x:string, [<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out>]y:int byref) =
    do y <- 3
    member __.X = x

let (myT, n) = MyType("test")
```

As a minor point, note that the tuples in your match statement are backwards: the return value comes first, so they should be `(_,false)` and `(mutex, true)`.

Comment: Is there any way to hint compiler to use constructor with exactly 3 arguments?

Comment: @Konstantin - not to my knowledge.

Comment: @kvb: Shouldn't that be `(false, _)` and `(true, mutex)`?

Comment: Do you know why `(System.Console.Write : string -> unit)(value)` is allowed, but not `(new Mutex : bool * string * bool -> Mutex)(false, i.ToString())`?

Comment: @Daniel - no, the original post has been updated so that all of the fixes I mentioned have been incorporated.

Comment: @Daniel - as to your other question, I don't know the answer.  Note that you can use constructors as static member constraints: `let inline ctor3 x y z = (^t : (new : _*_*_ -> ^t)(x,y,z))`.

Comment: @kvb: Why is the order of the returned tuple different between constructors and methods? `Dictionary.TryGetValue`, e.g., returns `bool * 'V`.

Comment: @Daniel - it's consistent; in the case of TryGetValue the return value is the bool indicating success/failure and the out param is the value; in the Mutex constructor the return value is the mutex and the out param is the bool indicating success/failure.  In either case, the return value occurs first in the tuple.